# Android store array of Bitmaps

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to know which is the best choice of array implementation in Android to store Bitmaps. Is it a good idea to store bitmaps in `ArrayList<Bitmap>` or it's not a good solution.

I am trying to store like 5 different bitmaps created programmatically in my application and store them in array,them draw 'em to e canvas,but it's not working properly.

Here is what I'm doing :

```
//beginning
ArrayList<Bitmap> temp = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

//in some function where mBitmap is been created
temp.add(mBitmap);

//in my custom class which extends View
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp.get(temp.size()-1));
mCanvas.drawBitmap(bm);
invalidate();
```

but the bitmap from temp is never added to my `mCanvas`.

Any ideas why and which is the best way to store bitmaps in Array in Android/Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) for Bitmap caching. Please read [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: LruCache is for API LEVEL 12, I'm using API LVL 7.

Comment: You can use android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to store bitmaps in ArrayList use LruCache with soft reference

```
 LruCache<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache;
 cache = new LruCache<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>(8*1024*1024)
```